# Can't capture lwc dispatched event in parent aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, customevent

I have a custom lwc component embedded inside another custom aura component.

This lwc dispatches custom event with data for aura to retrieve and process but I can't get any info although it's capturing the event.

customlwc.js

```
handledataChange(event){
    this.dispatchEvent('handleResponse', { message : event.detail.value });
}
```

customaura.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">
    <c:customlwc onhandleResponse="{!c.handleResponse}"/>
</aura:component>
```

customaura.js

```
({
    handleResponse: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event.getParam('message')) //this displays undefined
    },
})
```

Is there something I'm missing or isn't this the proper way to retrieve event info?

**EDIT (added lwc code for event launch)**

```
 @wire (getInitialInfo, {recordId : '$recordId'}) wiredGetInitialInfo ({error, data}){
    //Data
    if(data){
        //Success
        if(data.success){
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('handleSCResponse', { message : 'Operation completed successfully' })); 
        }
        //Error
        else{
            //for enclosing aura 
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('handleSCResponse'), { message : 'Error found '});
        }
    }
    //Error
    else if(error){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('handleSCResponse'), { message : 'Unexpected error' });
    }
}
```

Comment: Csn you add the code where you have fired the event from lwc?

Comment: @rahulgawale I've added the code now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your event name does not match here.

```
<c:customlwc onhandleResponse="{!c.handleResponse}"/>
```

You are firing event with name = `handleSCResponse`, so you need to prefix `on` to your event name, ex `onhandlescresponse`. The corrected code of handling it from the parent component is below.

```
<c:customlwc onhandlescresponse="{!c.handleResponse}"/>
```

---

So in detail, this is how you fire an event.

```
const eventName = 'onhandlescresponse';
const event = new CustomEvent(eventName, {
    detail: { message: 'Operation completed successfully' }
});
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This is how you handle it.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">
    <c:customlwc onhandlescresponse="{!c.handleResponse}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Although it is supported in the aura parent, its recommended to give the lowercase name for an event.

Answer (score 2):

There are some changes you need to do:

1) The name of the event should always be in small letters.[ handleResponse -> handleresponse]

2) For firing the event write -

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('handlescresponse'),  {
        detail: { message: 'Unexpected error.' }
    });
```

For more information see section "Sending Events to an Enclosing Aura Component" in - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-for-aura-developers/communicate-with-events

Comment: The event name need not be lowercase.

Comment: The DOM event standard for event names - 

No uppercase letters,
No spaces,
Use underscores to separate words.

Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch

Also, correct me If I am wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you are right, that is not recommended, when you are handling event from another lwc, and does not even let you save the component.  but for aura components, it accepts the capital letters as well, and even its case insensitive in aura parent. We should always go with a lowercase name for even name. thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in place of your aura component

While creating custom event use following:
Because we can't use capital letters in the name of the event, so use this code to dispatch events.

```js
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('handlescresponse', { message : 'Operation completed successfully' }));
```

then for handling event use following code

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">
    <c:customlwc onhandlescresponse="{!c.handleResponse}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Hope this works fine

Comment: Can you describe what is different about your code vs. molinet's and why this approach would work?

Comment: I used this approach and this worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

[Link to Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components)

If you need to send a primitive type and not a complex object in the event detail, another approach is something like this-

```
handledataChange(event){
    let message = event.detail.value;
    this.dispatchEvent('handleResponse', { detail : message });
}
```

The rest of the Aura code will work as is.

Doing something like this also works-

```
this.dispatchEvent('handleResponse', { detail : {message : event.detail.value } );
```

In both the cases, event.getParam('message') should give you the value in Aura.